# IntelliJ ajc: how to make exclusions from aspectj-maven-plugin work?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I'm using the ajc compiler in IntelliJ, as well as the aspectj-maven-plugin, where I declare the following exclusions:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/EmployeeAccessAspect.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When I compile using `mvn compile`, everything is fine and the `EmployeeAccessAspect` aspect is correctly ignored.

However, if I `Make` the project in IntelliJ, it will just weave all the aspects that it finds (and totally ignore the maven exclusions).

I can always hack the ajc compiler options or aspect path to achieve what I want, but it would make me change two places if I have to exclude an aspect for some reason.

Is there any way to make the maven plugin and the ajc compilation in sync? I am using IntelliJ 15.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can confirm that

- it does not work in IDEA,
- JetBrains [knows about it](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6757) at least since 2013,
- I have [commented on this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6757#comment=27-1266125),
- what you want does work in Eclipse (AspectJ is an Eclipse project, so the IDE support there is considerably better).

There is not much more I can say about it other than it is a known issue which is not considered a bug, but a new feature by JetBrains (see the ticket type there).